# Sequencing in Dataframe pyspark

Tags: rdd, pyspark

I Have a data source and need to add one additional sequence column while loading into the target.
I'm converting it into RDD and using `zipWithIndex()` function.
however, I'm getting:

> an error occurred while calling
> z:org:pache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe

Any specific package that I'm missing on glue.

Note: cannot sort the data

Comment: importing the below package:

Comment: import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.contxt import Spark.context, SparkConf
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from awsglue.job import job
from pyspark.rdd import RDD
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

Comment: df_1 = datasource0.toDF()
df_2 = df_1.withColumn('new_column', (lit(1)))

df_3 = df2.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1] + index)).toDF()